# check server change every 10 minutes and show changed in notification

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-service, android-notifications

I working on new project that **I want to every 10 minutes show me the changed parameter from server in notification.**
and it should work in the background and if it's possible when application is closed.

I get changed parameter from server and it's ok now.

but I can't find the any document or stack web to read it.

thanks

Comment: How can you "get" changed parameter from server, if you don't know how to "read it"?

Comment: *"it should work in the background"* Then create a background task on the server that run every 10 minutes and saves the information in a data store (database, local server file, whatever), then add web request for querying that information.